# So, basically my code is printing None after printing the statement I want it to print. How can I stop this None from printing

Tags: python, methods, overloading

So, basically my code is printing None after printing the statement I want it to print. How can I stop this None from printing

```
class Panda:
    def __init__(self,name,gender,age):
        self.name=name
        self.gender=gender
        self.age=age
    def sleep(self,time=None):
        self.time=time
        if self.time!=None:
            if self.time>=3 and self.time<=5:
                self.food='Mixed Veggies'
            if self.time>=6 and self.time<=8:
                self.food='Eggplant & Tofu'
            if self.time>=9 and self.time<=11:
                self.food='Broccoli Chicken'
            print('{} sleeps {} hours daily and should have {}'.format(self.name,self.time,self.food))
        else:
            print("{}'s duration is unknown thus should have only bamboo leaves".format(self.name))

panda1=Panda("Kunfu","Male", 5)
panda2=Panda("Pan Pan","Female",3)
panda3=Panda("Ming Ming","Female",8)
print(panda2.sleep(10))
print(panda1.sleep(4))
print(panda3.sleep())
```

Comment: The problem is that your function `sleep` performs the print itself. so it would be enough to just call `panda2.sleep(10)` without enclosing it in a `print` command. because `sleep` has no return function, it implicitly returns `None`. so the `print` calls are printing None after the function `sleep` has finished(returned).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `print` function doesn't return in Python, it just writes to `stdout`; so, when you call the `sleep` method for the instance, it just prints `None`.

To fix this, what you have to do is either `return` instead of printing in `sleep` or just call it without enclosing it in the `print` statement.

Result would be like this, for example:

```
class Panda:
    def __init__(self,name,gender,age):
        self.name=name
        self.gender=gender
        self.age=age
    def sleep(self,time=None):
        self.time=time
        if self.time!=None:
            if self.time>=3 and self.time<=5:
                self.food='Mixed Veggies'
            if self.time>=6 and self.time<=8:
                self.food='Eggplant & Tofu'
            if self.time>=9 and self.time<=11:
                self.food='Broccoli Chicken'
            return '{} sleeps {} hours daily and should have {}'.format(self.name,self.time,self.food)
        else:
            return "{}'s duration is unknown thus should have only bamboo leaves".format(self.name)

panda1=Panda("Kunfu","Male", 5)
panda2=Panda("Pan Pan","Female",3)
panda3=Panda("Ming Ming","Female",8)
print(panda2.sleep(10))
print(panda1.sleep(4))
print(panda3.sleep())
```

or

```
class Panda:
    def __init__(self,name,gender,age):
        self.name=name
        self.gender=gender
        self.age=age
    def sleep(self,time=None):
        self.time=time
        if self.time!=None:
            if self.time>=3 and self.time<=5:
                self.food='Mixed Veggies'
            if self.time>=6 and self.time<=8:
                self.food='Eggplant & Tofu'
            if self.time>=9 and self.time<=11:
                self.food='Broccoli Chicken'
            print('{} sleeps {} hours daily and should have {}'.format(self.name,self.time,self.food))
        else:
            print("{}'s duration is unknown thus should have only bamboo leaves".format(self.name))

panda1=Panda("Kunfu","Male", 5)
panda2=Panda("Pan Pan","Female",3)
panda3=Panda("Ming Ming","Female",8)
panda2.sleep(10)
panda1.sleep(4)
panda3.sleep()
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't notice it before it got pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

So the first print statement is due to the `print` function in the `sleep` method. The `None` is being printed as you have `print(panda1.sleep())`. The `sleep` method doesn't return anything, and hence the `None`.

To get rid of the `None`, you can simply use `panda1.sleep()` rather than `print(panda1.sleep())`.

However, a better alternative might be to return the message you want your `sleep` function to print, and then use `print(panda1.sleep())`

Comment: the standard input had `print(panda1.sleep())` and such, so `return` in method is the way to go for me