# why i am getting None between print results? using pycharm as IDE

Tags: python

i am getting None after print(my_dog.name.title())
print(my_dog.sit())
print(my_dog.rolling()), although its not error but i want to know why i am getting this. i am using pycharm Ide

```py
class dog():
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    def sit(self):
        print(self.name+" is now sitting")
    def rolling(self):
        print(self.name+" is now rolling")

#Making an Instance from a Class
my_dog = dog('willie',6) #my dog is instance here

print(my_dog.name.title())
print(my_dog.sit())
print(my_dog.rolling())
print("my dog is "+str(my_dog.age))


C:\Users\office\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/office/Desktop/python/classes2.py
Willie
willie is now sitting
None                      
willie is now rolling
None                     
my dog is 6

Process finished with exit code 0
```

as you can see , i am getting None after willie is now sitting and again after willie is now rolling

Comment: Does this answer your question? [So, basically my code is printing None after printing the statement I want it to print. How can I stop this None from printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63711545/so-basically-my-code-is-printing-none-after-printing-the-statement-i-want-it-to)

Answer (score 0):

```py
class dog():
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    def sit(self):
        print(self.name+" is now sitting")
    def rolling(self):
        print(self.name+" is now rolling")

#Making an Instance from a Class
my_dog = dog('willie',6) #my dog is instance here

print(my_dog.name.title())
my_dog.sit()
my_dog.rolling()
print("my dog is "+str(my_dog.age))
C:\Users\office\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/office/Desktop/python/classes2.py
Willie
willie is now sitting
willie is now rolling
my dog is 6

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You print both in the **function** and in your **code**
You can use **return** instead of **print** in the function

```
...
def sit(self):
    return self.name+" is now sitting"
def rolling(self):
    return self.name+" is now rolling"
...
```

**or** do not **print** in your code

```
print(my_dog.name.title())
my_dog.sit() # Delete print
my_dog.rolling() # Delete print
print("my dog is "+str(my_dog.age))
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because, functions with no returns has a return type none.
Your print call is basically,

```
print(print('''blah blah'''))
```

that means, the internal print function is doing it's job and returning a None
the external print is printing the None returned by the internal print.

Answer (score 0):

### Use `return` instead of `print` in your Class `methods`

```
class dog():
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    def sit(self):
        return self.name+" is now sitting"
    def rolling(self):
        return self.name+" is now rolling"
        
#Making an Instance from a Class
my_dog = dog('willie',6) #my dog is instance here

print(my_dog.name.title())
print(my_dog.sit())
print(my_dog.rolling())
print("my dog is "+str(my_dog.age))
```

The reason why you are getting `None` is that -

`my_dog.sit()` method does not return anything and that is why when you `print` it shows `None` because **nothing is being returned** from the `sit()` method of the class.